# PHP Dropbox API - Page Not Found Error using files_put

Tags: php, dropbox-api

I am having problems trying to upload a file using PHP and the Dropbox API. When the cURL executes I get a page not found error. Which suggests a URL problem, but I cannot see that it is wrong.

The file exists and all the OAuth is working.

Screenshot of error:
[image: Page not found error]

This is the code being used - am I missing something here?

```
$filePathName = "/path_to_file/my_image.png";
$url = "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/sandbox/my_folder/my_image.png";

$headers = array("Content-Type: ".mime_content_type($filePathName)."\r\nContent-Length: ".filesize($filePathName)."\r\n".
    "Authorization: OAuth oauth_version=\"1.0\", oauth_signature_method=\"PLAINTEXT\", oauth_consumer_key=\"".DROPBOX_APP_KEY."\", oauth_token=\"".DROPBOX_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN."\", oauth_signature=\"".DROPBOX_APP_SECRET."&".DROPBOX_OAUTH_ACCESS_SECRET."\""
);

$fh = fopen($filePathName, "rb");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($filePathName));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$apiResponse = curl_exec($ch);

fclose($fh);

die("Response:<br />".$apiResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

See also https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api

The url structure for uploading files is `https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/<root>/<path>?param=val`. Where root is root The root relative to which path is specified. Valid values are sandbox and dropbox. So you're missing the root in your url.

Comment: Thanks Bass. I am already using that page for reference. I have made a typo in the code example I put on here (oops!) and missed the root value (which is sandbox). I will edit the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix it!

The issue was with the way I was constructing the headers. It should have been this:

```
$headers = array(
    "'Content-Type: ".mime_content_type($filePathName)."'",
    "'Content-Length: ".filesize($filePathName)."'",
    "Authorization: OAuth oauth_version=\"1.0\", oauth_signature_method=\"PLAINTEXT\", oauth_consumer_key=\"".DROPBOX_APP_KEY."\", oauth_token=\"".DROPBOX_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN."\", oauth_signature=\"".DROPBOX_APP_SECRET."&".DROPBOX_OAUTH_ACCESS_SECRET."\""
);
```

`Content-Type` and `Content-Length` no longer end with `\r\n` and are now surrounded with `'` and are separate elements in the array.

I got a clue to this as I used the `curl_getinfo` function and the `http_code` was 400, meaning a bad request. This moved me away from being stuck on the "page not found" error returned by Dropbox and made me further investigate the headers.